# NPM private repo, saving the package location in package.json

Tags: npm, npm-install

It is possible to configure a repository location for NPM in the `publishConfig`, so that when `npm publish` is run the package get published to that specific repository/location. Now I was wondering if it is possible to do the same with installing. `npm install --save my-package --registry http://some.repo.com:4832` installs a package from a specific repository, but it requires the `--registry` parameter every time `npm-install` is run.

Another option is to configure the NPM installation to that specific repository. The downside of this solution is that every time a developer comes along, s/he needs to add that specific repository. It's not all that problematic, but as with many things, it can and should be automated.

So in short, I want:

```
"dependencies": {
  "lodash": "^4.17.5",
  "my-package": { "version": "^1.0.2", registry: "http://some.repo.com:4832" }
}
```

So that becomes automated. I have checked the NPM documentation and have been googling, but I can't find an answer. Does anyone know if and then- how this can be done?

Thanks in advance :)